# CryptographyDeprecationWarning with python 2

Tags: python

Lately, I got this warning:

> CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Support for it is now deprecated in cryptography, and will be removed in a future release.

Should I upgrade Gspread or Python ? Cause all code are in Python 2, it is hard to move to python 3.

Comment: Future releases won't support Python 2, but the current release still does.  You won't be able to update your crypto library, but there is no reason you can't continue using the current one for as long as it suits your purposes.  You won't get the newest stuff, but that should be okay.

Comment: Tks alot Frank Yellin.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently started to see this on macOS 10.15.7 (Catalina) when running Google Cloud tools written in Python (`gcloud` and `gsutil`). For example:

```bsh
$ gsutil ls gs://<object store bucket and object path>
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/OpenSSL/crypto.py:12: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Support for it is now deprecated in cryptography, and will be removed in the next release.
  from cryptography import x509
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/OpenSSL/crypto.py:12: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Support for it is now deprecated in cryptography, and will be removed in the next release.
  from cryptography import x509
<expected output>
```

This solves it:

```bsh
$ pip install cryptography==2.2.2
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting cryptography==2.2.2
  Using cached cryptography-2.2.2-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl (1.5 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: ipaddress; python_version < "3" in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from cryptography==2.2.2) (1.0.22)
...
Successfully installed cryptography-2.2.2
```

Note that it only installs it for the current user. It may or may not be safe to do this with `sudo` and update the system-wide copy. This was good enough for me, and lower risk.

Answer (score 2):

pip install cryptography==2.2.2
Works fine with out warnings